# How to use .loc over a column with lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my df:

```
    feature_name    combo                           p_val   *
0   VC9             [rest_closed, immediate_recall] 0.0053  **
1   VC9             [rest_music, immediate_recall]  0.0345  *
2   VC9             [rest_wonder, rest_closed]      0.0010  ***
3   VC9             [rest_wonder, rest_music]       0.0043  **
4   VC9             [rest_wonder, rest_open]        0.0075  **
5   Theta           [rest_closed, immediate_recall] 0.0098  **
6   Theta           [rest_wonder, rest_closed]      0.0038  **
7   Theta           [statements, rest_closed]       0.0187  *
8   Gamma           [rest_closed, clock]            0.0230  *
9   Gamma           [rest_closed, d1]               0.0111  *
10  Gamma           [rest_closed, immediate_recall] 0.0155  *
11  Gamma           [rest_closed, nb1]              0.0396  *
12  Gamma           [rest_wonder, rest_closed]      0.0065  **
13  Gamma           [statements, rest_closed]       0.0175  *
```

I an trying to reach the p_val through the feature_name & combo.
meaning - I want to insert for examplt 'VC9' and [rest_closed, immediate_recall] and to get the matching p_val.
everything I tried failed...
this is what I have right now -

```
for feature in features:
    
    for comb in combinations:
        pval = df_sigs.loc[(df_sigs['feature_name'].isin([feature])) & (df_sigs['combo'].isin([comb])), df_sigs['p_val']]
```

And this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

(I want to print the p_val over a plot so I don't need it for more than the one loop)

when I tried other things I also got this error many time:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

(for example when I used np.where)

I seriously tried anything I can think of - creating another column of strings that combines the two elemnts of the lists.. unlisting, turning the list to a tuple. I feel like I am missing something very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.loc`, you can use the in-built `__getitem__` method of pandas, like so.

Further, to filter on a column including a list, you need to make a lambda mask to get true value for each row in the column

```
for feature in features:

    for comb in combinations:
        tmp = df[(df['feature_name'] == feature) & (df['combo'].apply(lambda x: x == comb))]
        pval = tmp['p_val'].values[0]
```

Comment: it still gives me this error: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: fixed it, should work for you now

Answer (score 1):

```
feature_name = 'VC9'
combo = ['rest_closed', 'immediate_recall']

# Initialize the p_val variable to None
p_val = None

# Iterate over the rows of the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  # Check if the feature_name and combo match the given values
  if row['feature_name'] == feature_name and set(row['combo']) == set(combo):
    p_val = row['p_val']
    break

# Print the p_val
print(p_val)
```

Comment: not working :( [error message: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare]

Comment: I'm sorry @user20646185. This error is happening because I m trying to compare a list of combo values with a single combo value. Maybe `isin` function could solve this issue. I have updated my code in a classic way (with a for loop, index). This one is working.

Answer (score 0):

df_sigs[(df_sigs['feature_name']=='VC9') & (df_sigs['combo']=="['rest_closed', 'immediate_recall']")].p_val.iloc[0]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).